# I can't understand how django's path() works

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I've tried looking at the documentation, and read several questions of the same subject, and can't wrap my head around it. I've been trying to follow the tutorial, and while I've gotten pretty far I still cannot understand what the path function does.

What does it do on this snippet?

```
path('', views.index, name='index'),
```

What about this one?

```
path('books/', views.BookListView.as_view(), name='books'),
```

Or this one?

```
path('catalog/', include('catalog.urls')),
```

Comment: This question is not a good fit for Stack Overflow format, but have a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're in your root project directory, meaning, the one that has your `settings.py`... If the following `path()` is inside your `urls.py`, as long as you have `from . import views` at your imports... This `path()` function means that when you `python manage.py runserver` in your terminal, and you get 127.0.0.1:8000/, the following `path()` will be the home page, or 127.0.0.1:8000/. If you want it to work for something other than the default success page though *(as you have it with the path() below)*, you will need to add a function called `index` into your views.py of the same directory.

```
path('', views.index, name='index'),
```

The following one is a class based view. Since you're new, I strongly suggest you stay away from them. When I knew nothing they made everything far more confusing, because there was no obvious control flow, so I had no idea how they worked. But to answer your question, it does the same as the one above, but if you typed `127.0.0.1:8000/books` into your browser when the development server is running, it would trigger a class based view *(function)* that can be referred to as `books` whenever you want to make a link to it for a user to click.

```
path('books/', views.BookListView.as_view(), name='books'),
```

The last one means you have created an app called "catalog" in your terminal with `python manage.py startapp catalog`. After having done that, you will have to create a urls.py file in that app folder, and from there you can make urlpatterns specific to that app. For example, `127.0.0.1:8000/catalog` would be the "home page" of the catalog app. But any urlpattern you put inside the urls.py of the catalog app would only require something like `path('games/', views.games, name='games')` *(to make an example of a catalog for games)*.

But this `path()` in this file, of this app, would automatically have `/catalog/` before it. So the `games/` example above is actually `127.0.0.1:8000/catalog/games/`. And going there would trigger the view *(function)* to give the catalog for games, as long as you set it to.

And to make it more efficient so you could refer to urls properly without getting them mixed up, in the urls.py file of this catalog app, you should put `app_name = 'catalog'` above the url patterns. Then you could refer to them like `{% url 'catalog:view_name' %}`

```
path('catalog/', include('catalog.urls')),
```

If this is still confusing, I strongly suggest you check out things on udemy.com for Django 2. Go through a bunch, and it'll help a lot.

Comment: This helps quite a lot, thank you. I know it's generally a bad idea to post questions like this, but I legitimately could not understand how this function worked. Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem. Just make sure you check out udemy.com. Lots of good stuff there to make it easier for beginners.